# Vue.js: Issue with calculating prices from selected services

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function called getTotalFixedPrice as a computed property which calculates fixed prices from a service. The problem is the sum wont update when a user changes to a different service, only when a user adds a new service by clicking the plus icon. I can see that editeditem updates when I change to a different service, but it does not update the sum on change

[image]

Code (Estimates.vue):

```
getTotalFixedPrice(){
                return this.totalFixedPrice = this.editedItem.service
                        .map(val => parseInt(val.fixed_price))
                        .filter(val => val)
                        .reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
            },
```

Component editservice

```
<edit-service                                     
    v-for="(item, index) in editedItem.service"
    :item="item"
    :editedItem="editedItem"
    :key="index"  
    :index="index"                                         
    :services="services.services"
    :items="editedItem"
    :edit="edit"
    @onEdit="onEdit($event)"
 />
```

```
 headers: [ { text: 'id', align: 'start', sortable: false, value: 'id' },
                { text: 'Client', value: 'client' },
                { text: 'Date', value: 'date' },
                { text: 'Expire Date', value: 'expire_date' },
                { text: 'Number', value: 'number' },
                { text: 'Reference', value: 'reference' },
                { text: 'Services', value: 'service' },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
            ],
            
            // Search value
            search: '',
            inputs: [AddNewService],
            // Boolean values
            dialog: false,
            dialogDelete: false,
            selectedValues: [],

            totalFixedPrice: 0,
            totalHourlyPrice: 0,

            editedIndex: -1,

            edit: false,
            selectedEdit: false,

            inputs: [],

            // Data to be sent
            data: {},

            // Edited items
            editedItem: { client: null, date: null, expire_date: null, number: null, reference: null,service: [] },
            
            getPrices: [],

            // Default items
            defaultItem: { client: '', date: '', expire_date: '', number: '', reference: '', service: [] },
            
            selected: '',
            project: ''
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing reactivity somewhere, show `data`

Comment: Feel free to double check what you have in your devtools too.

Comment: @kissu  the problem is that the fixed price only updates for every second added service. When i add a service, a new item gets added to editeditem with the selected service but the doom doesnt reflect this update until the next service gets added